# Showing $S_n$ is indecomposable.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups, direct-product

This is **Exercise 3.3.2** of Robinson's *"A Course in the Theory of Groups (Second Edition)"*. According to [this search](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bsymmetric-groups%5D+indecomposable+), it is new to MSE.

### The Details:

Robinson's book defines indecomposable groups via $\Omega$-subgroups by setting $\Omega=\varnothing$ in the definition of $\Omega$-indecomposable, so it is rather complicated; however, it is equivalent to Roman's definition on page 75 of *"Fundamentals of Group Theory: An Advanced Approach"*:

> A nontrivial group $G$ is said to be *indecomposable* if $G$ cannot be written as an [internal direct product](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3985240/104041) of two proper subgroups, that is, $$G=H ⨝ K\implies ((H=G)\lor(K=G)).$$

### The Question:

> Prove that $S_n$ is indecomposable.

### Thoughts:

My first thoughts were as follows . . .

Suppose $S_n=H ⨝ K$ for proper $H,K\le S_n$ such that $H\neq S_n$. My aim is then to show that $K=S_n$.

That $K\subseteq S_n$ is clear from $K\le S_n$.

Let $\sigma\in S_n$. I require $\sigma\in K$ in order for $S_n\subseteq K$. Here, however, I am stuck; I mean: I could try & see where the statement that $H\neq S_n$ comes into play but I have no ideas there.

---

Thus I decided to try induction on $n$. (This might work since, by convention, $n$ is assumed to be finite.)

The group $S_1$ is degenerate here.

However, $S_2\cong \Bbb Z_2$ is clearly indecomposable. (It's overkill but this follows from the Fundamental Theorem of Finitely Generated Abelian Groups.)

Suppose $S_r$ is indecomposable for some $r\in \Bbb N\setminus\{1\}$.

Consider when $n=r+1$. We have some $T\le S_{r+1}$ such that $T\cong S_r$. Where do I go from here?

---

My intuition is more in line with my first thoughts, for I can sense in some way that $H\neq S_n$ would force $H\cong 1$ and $K=S_n$. But how do I show this?

---

I am surprised that this property of $S_n$ is not easy to find online. It has me wondering whether it's even true or, worse, whether it's somewhat trivial.

Please help :)

Comment: $S_n$ is simple for $n\ne4$, so doesn’t even have normal subgroups…

Comment: @runway44 That's not correct, right? You mean $A_n$ is simple for those values of $n$.

Comment: Err, yes. :) $ $

Comment: This result may not be easy to find online, but it is easy to find a list of all normal subgroups of $S_n$ online (for $n \ge 5$ there are only three, $1$, $A_n$ and $S_n$), and the result that you want follows easily from that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $n=1$, it is trivial.
For $n=2$, since $S_n$ is a cyclic group of prime order, the result is also obvious.

Let $n\geq 3$. Suppose that there exists proper subgroups $H,K$ such that $S_n$ is a internal direct product of $H$ and $K$. Then note that $H,K$ are proper normal subgroups of $S_n$ and $|S_n|=|H||K|$.

If $n\neq 4$, note that the only proper normal subgroup of $S_n$ is $A_n$. Since $S_n$ does not have a normal subgroup of order $2$, this is a contradiction.

Consider $n=4$. The only proper normal subgroups of $S_n$ are $A_n$ and the Klein $4$-group $V$. Since $S_n$ does not have a normal subgroup of order $2$ or $6$, this is also a contradiction.

Comment: Hang on: $S_3$ is non-abelian, so cannot be cyclic.

Comment: @Shaun Corrected. The only proper normal subgroup of $S_3$ is $A_3$ so similar arguments follow.