# Question about indecomposable group

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

There is a classic question about indecomposable group as follows:

> Prove that a group $G$ is indecomposable if and only if whenever $H$ and $K$ are normal subgroups such that $G=H\times K$, then $H=\langle e\rangle$ or $K=\langle e\rangle$

My understanding of writing a group $G$ as the direct/internal direct product of two of its subgroups $H$ and $K$, and for all $h\in H$ with $G=HK$, $k\in K$, the following conditions are equivalent:

1. Both $H$ and $K$ are normal subgroups of $G$ and for any $g\in G$, $g$ can be uniquely expressed as $g=hk$
2. $H\times K\cong G$ under the canonical mapping $(h,k)\mapsto hk$
3. Both $H$ and $K$ are normal subgroups of $G$ and $H\cap K=\{e\}$

Also my understanding of the statement $H\cap K=\{e\}$ is the identity element $e \in G$ such that $e\in H\cap K$. How is this the negation of $H=\langle e\rangle$ or $K=\langle e\rangle$?  I am thinking that when a group $G$cannot be written as the direct/internal direct product of two of its subgroups, condition (3) above must not be met.  I think should somehow negate the statement: $H\cap K=\{e\}$.  Also I am trying to express the statement in the language of propositional calculus to translate it into mathematical notations.

**Can someone tell me if my understanding is correct?**

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use `$\langle a\rangle$` for $\langle a\rangle$.

Comment: @Shaun kk.  I will edit my post.

Comment: "How is this the negation of $H=\langle e\rangle$ or $K=\langle e\rangle$? " - I am sure you see that it is not the negation. It is a different statement.

Comment: What is your definition of an indecomposable group?

Comment: @DerekHolt that is why I am asking, I don't think it is.  The definition of an indecomposable group for a group $G$ if it is not the direct product of two of its proper normal subgroups.
I am using Hungerford's undergrad abstract algebra text 3rd edition.

Comment: Further to Derek Holt's comment, Robinson defines "indecomposable" as the property you're trying to show; see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4171124/104041).

Comment: It is very hard to make sense of your comment. What does "that is why I am asking, I don't think it is" mean?

Comment: @Shaun I feel that the definition of indecomposable group has to do with doing something to the condition in the definition of internal direct product.  I am guessing failing one of its equivalent conditions.

Comment: @DerekHolt I am trying to understand what it means for a group to not being able to be written as a direct/internal direct product of its proper normal subgroups.  Since the definition of direct/internal direct product for groups has multiple equivalent conditions.  Then one of those must be violated.  It just so happens that I need to show $H=\langle e\rangle$ or $K=\langle e\rangle$, and I am trying to see which corresponding conditions does that negates.

Comment: Suppose that $G$ is indecomposable and $G$ is the internal direct product $H \times K$. Then, by your definition, at least one of $H$ and $K$, say $H$,  cannot be a proper normal subgroup of $G$. It is certainly a normal subgroup of $G$, so it must fail to be proper i.e. $H=G$. But from that it is easy to deduce that $K = \{e\}$.

Comment: @DerekHolt if $H=G$, then $G\cap K=K=\{e\}$.  Hence $K=\{e\}$.  When you say that $H$ fails to be proper normal subgroup of $G$, it is that $H$ fails to be a proper subgroup of $G$ that is important between proper and normal?